# Can Gmail automatically base "send from" address on the "to" address?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

**In short:**
In Gmail, is there a way to let the "send from" address change automatically depending on which of my accounts it was sent to?

**In long:**

I recently joined a team (of developers) and they provided me with an email address on their domain (for if I have business with a client or something).

- Anything sent to **me@team.com** is forwarded by the **team.com** mail server
- I'm using Gmails **"send mail as"** functionality to send email through **smtp.team.com**.
- I receive emails and I can send them, **so that works**
- I have my default **"send as"** address setup as ***me@Gmail.com***, which I would like to keep since I send 90% of my mail through there.

Now I'm wondering how to do the following, if at all possible:

- when I receive an email at **me@team.com** (as opposed to ***me@Gmail.com***), and I reply to it, my **"send as"** address will change automatically to **me@team.com**
- I can do it manually, but I know I'm going to forget sooner or later, confusing the hell out of people since the team lets me use a pseudonym.

I hope my question makes sense, and I'm sure it's easily answered by a "no, not possible" or "yes, option X in tab Y".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes**

In your Gmail settings, under "Accounts and Import", if you have multiple "send mail as" accounts set up you can choose to always default to your Gmail account or to respond with the account to which the message was sent.

[image: "send from" Gmail settings]

Comment: Nice, thanks. That probably means there's no way to do it on a per-account basis? I have several legacy accounts that dump into my more 'permanent' gmail, so ideally I would answer those with my main account, and only the 'team' account with a different address...

Comment: Correct, although if you haven't set them up as "send as" accounts, it'll default to your main address.

Comment: hadn't thought of that. As Iḿ trying to discourage people to use my old accounts there is no reason to have them as send-as (except for unsubscribing to spammy newsletters). This is perfect.

Comment: Note that the "Reply from same address" only works if the original is sent "To" the individual address that matches one of your Send As entries. It will not work if the original "To:" is a distribution list, which hides your individual address. In that case the "Send As" address will not match any "To" address, and it will use your default Send As address, instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to auto-select "from" address when you COMPOSE, as well, you could try this UserScript (which you can install with something like [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo):

[GMail "Send From" Auto Selector](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/71859)

Comment: Sadly, the script is no longer maintained.

Comment: Anyone know of an alternative to this script?

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Sad that it's no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have not found a way to do this directly, but I have found a useful workaround (thanks to [Michael Sinanian](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67091/can-i-configure-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-gmail-send-from-addresses))

**Cmd-shift-F selects the from address**, making it easy to change.

You just need a reminder to do it.

1. You need to have a "from" address that you don't actually want to use.
2. In Gmail › Settings › Accounts, make this the default "from" address
3. In Gmail › Settings › General, add a default signature for this address:

   CMD-SHIFT-F

Then "Save Changes".

Now, when you compose email, **you will get a message with the keyboard shortcut to use the correct "from" account**.

The message will disappear as soon as you change addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this feature, but I do see that it is at least possible for replies to maintain the original mail which a message was sent.  [Lifehacker notes how.](http://lifehacker.com/156549/gmail-adds-smart-replying):

> To enable the new feature, go to Settings -> Accounts and change the "When I receive a message sent to one of my addresses:" option to "Reply from the same address my message was sent to."

Comment: Can you summarize that link, so that if it goes dead, your answer is still dead? It's better for answers to standalone, without relying on external links staying alive.