# In Gmail, can I base my “send from” address on a filter/label?

Tags: gmail

**In short:** 
In Gmail, is there a way to let the "send from" address change automatically depending on which label the mail has?

**In long:**
I have 4 accounts connected to Gmail.

Lets say *golob@private1*, *golob@private2*, *golob@work1* and *golob@work2*.

Currently I'm using "Reply from the same address the message was sent to".
But what, I want to have is the send from in reply would be based on the address the message came to (or based on a label), but it wouldn't necessary be the very same address.

So for e-mails sent to *golob@private1*, *golob@private2*, I want to reply with golob@private1 and for e-mails sent to *golob@work1*, *golob@work2* I want to reply as golob@work1.

I know, I can install scripts for it, but I want it to be portable so that the solution would be base solely on Gmail options.

NOTE: The question is different and way more complex then [In Gmail, can I base my "send from" address on a filter?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/in-gmail-can-i-base-my-send-from-address-on-a-filter)

Comment: No, not with native Gmail.