# Can I configure custom keyboard shortcut for Gmail send-from addresses?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an existing way to invoke specific send-from addresses with keyboard shortcuts? I'm aware you can use <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to switch to the `Send-From` field, but then you still have to manually select which address you want to send from. I'd like to be able to modify that key command such that an extra key lets me send from a different address, like: <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for sending from my university address, or <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for sending from work. Is this possible?