# Is there a way to select a 'From:' alias based on intended recipient?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

There is an old related (but not duplicate) [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/can-gmail-automatically-base-send-from-address-on-the-to-address) about automatically replying from an alias email address when an email is **received** to that alias.

I have a catch-all address, `me@example.com`, set up using GSuite (free, grandfathered from Google Apps For Your Domain if it makes a difference). I use this to set up individual addresses for different products/companies/etc.

Sometimes I need to send an email from one of those aliases, for example in the situation where *Foo, Incorporated* will only deal with the registered email address `fooinc@example.com` for security reasons. I can set up an alias and send an email so that it comes from `fooinc@example.com`.

However, it's easy to overlook changing the 'send from' address. **When *composing* an email, is there any way to automatically set the 'From:' (send from) address based on the intended recipient?** For example, a filter such that any composed email address at a particular domain (eg `*@fooincorporated.com`) gets sent from a specified alias (eg `fooinc@example.com`).

A [previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28480/190626) mentions a userscript ([GMail "Send From" Auto Selector](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/71859)), but the answer is from 2011 and neither the script or the answer is currently updated.

Comment: Feedback welcome! I hope both the example and non-duplicate nature of the question are clear :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to automatically reply using the alias that received the incoming email? if that is what you are looking for you can check this Gmail Help Center article, it explaines how to add an alias to your account and reply with it https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en. That article is updated so it will work, I hope that helps. Greetings.

Comment: Hi Mario. I do not want to automatically reply using the alias. As the bolded text in my question says, I would like to set the 'From' address **based on the recipient when *composing* an email** (not replying). In addition, it is good practice to include information from any links in your answer itself.